# Get xml add product image

Tags: xml, import, prestashop

I have a xml 
import product prestashop how to create product image to get on url

ex xml:

```
<item>
 <name>Note 8</name>
    ....
 <image>http://xxxx.jpg</image>
</item>
```

Prestashop add new product

```
$createProduct = new Product();
....
$createProduct->add();
```

How to add image on xml url

Good days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `copyImg()` function my making it public in `AdminImportController.php`. then your code will be

```
    include('config/config.inc.php');
    include('init.php'); 
    $xml=simplexml_load_file("example.xml");
    $createProduct = new Product();
    ....
    $createProduct->add();
    $image = new Image();
    $image->id_product = $createProduct->id;
    $image->position = Image::getHighestPosition($productID) + 1;
    $image->cover = true;
    if (($image->validateFields(false, true)) === true && ($image->validateFieldsLang(false, true)) === true && $image->add()) {
    if (!AdminImportController::copyImg($createProduct->id, $image->id, $xml->image,'products', false)){ $image->delete(); }
    }
```

Dont forget to make `compyImg()` public in `AdminImportController.php`